# React component not rendering also not showing up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

As you can see below the my react component is not rendering also in vscode its greyed out (line 2 first picture).
Dont know what I am doing wrong

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import counterComponent from './components/counterComponent';

function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment >
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <counterComponent/>
    </Fragment>
  )
};

export default App;
```

[image: app.js]

[image]

Comment: You should capitalize your component names so CounterComponent

Answer (score 3):

First of all capitalize your component names. so `CounterComponent` instead of `counterComponent`.

Second you're exporting counterComponent twice.

`export const` ....

and `export default` in the bottom. Choose one and change your import according to whichever you choose..

Answer (score 0):

You need to import counter component with {}
As its export const
Import {CounterComponet} from …

Comment: In the file you shared its with export const, not default

Answer (score 0):

because you are doing something wrong counterComponents correctly, look at you `App.js` file or the second Image and look at line number 2(it is a little dark-ish) because you are not using it right.
Also you are default and modular exporting `counterComponent` do any one of them, I usually do it like this

```
import React, { Fragment} from "react";

function counterComponent () {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h1>hello</h1>
        </Fragment>
    );
}

export default counterComponent;
```

If that doesn't work, My suggestion is check again if there is not any spelling mistake or you are importing from the right location

Comment: everything is correct

Comment: Did you change the counterComponent Syntax?

Comment: yea i did i still didnt work

Comment: If the above code didn't work, I really cant help you

Comment: only the component folder shows green with unmardked 'U'.I looked up internet and says its for untracked files. But I dont have any git repository.And i did a git status and it says there is no repository here. does this mean anything?

Comment: No Git isn't the problem